# password-store with git submodules

Tags: git, macos, git-submodules, gnupg, pgp

Git submodules in [pass](http://passwordstore.org) work quite well for using different sets of passwords. My only issue is that I cannot issue `git submodule` commands through `pass`.

For example,

```
pass git submodule foreach git pull
```

returns:

> fatal: /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.6.4/libexec/git-core/git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, within `~/.password-store`, `git submodule` commands work as expected